# problem with resources and android library project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having a problem adding resources to my Android project when i have a Library project referenced. This is what I'm seeing:

Both Projects compile and run fine.
When i have the library project linked and I want to add a string resource to the main project, the line is there in the **XML** file, everything compiles but the resources is not added to the R class. I've tried cleaning the project, removing the R class etc. But all the resources that were already there before i linked the Library are all present in R.
Also the resources that were present in both projects are correctly merged.

To work around this I need to unlink the library project, comment all the references to it in the main project and then all the resources i add are added to the R class. (then I need to re-link the library).

I'm using `Eclipse and ADT`.

What could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse has some issues with Android. Can you try - 1) Refreshing the resources folder of your main project, 2) Refreshing the whole of your main project, 3) Restarting eclipse ?

Comment: Also make sure you are using latest version of ADT.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Eclipse sometimes doesn't realize that it needs to regenerate the R.java file even with a clean + rebuild. it's the compile pass that fixes this but the resource references in code keep it from compiling. I've sometimes had to temporally comment out the lines that reference the resources just to get a clean compile. Then I uncomment those lines and suddenly everything is fine again.

Mixed with with linked libraries, Eclipse can get very flaky. Your solution of temporally turning library projects into non-library projects was the key for me today. Non-library + commented resource references + recompile + uncomment + re-library + recompile seems to be the magic formula.